# jQuery load() code not working in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, google-chrome, load

i am stuck here with a little jQuery Problem! I am using this code to load the content of a html file (bio.html) into a div containter (content). This works in IE8 and Firefox 6, but not in Google Chrome!

Any ideas what i might be doing wrong? Heres the Code:

```
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

```
<div id="content">
    hi
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){   

        $('#content').load('./html/bio.html');

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Any JavaScript console errors? Have you tried it with adding a 'complete' callback (the 3rd parameter in load())? Does the developer tool Network tab show an AJAX request? If so, check if it is returning an HTTP error code. (There is a same-domain security policy for most browsers--but it looks like that is not your problem here since you're using relative URIs.)

Comment: This question has been asked a few times. I posted this answer on a different question. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24376097/756329

Answer (score 2):

The issue is just that `.load()` for local files is blocked by Chrome for security reasons. If you are using it on a server it works, given that all of the files originate from the same place.

To enable a working version locally, start Chrome with a command line flag enabled by trying:

In Mac OS X, quit Chrome, enter in Terminal:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --allow-file-access-from-files
```

In Windows, quit Chrome, enter in Command Prompt:

```
chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files
```

(Maybe you actually have to have the path... I don't think so. If so, you'll have to find it yourself.)

In Linux, quit Chrome, enter something like this into the terminal:

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome --allow-file-access-from-files
```

Answer (score 1):

It works fine for me in chrome

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/512ef/2

try to look at developer's inspect tool if you see any unexpected errors. Be sure you're in http:// or https:// protocol, file:// will not work

Answer (score 1):

`.load()` will not work in Chrome if you are loading files from your local system.

Putting it on a server will resolve the issue.

Comment: Do you know a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are running this locally, is that correct? Chrome has some security features that prevent JQuery's load method to fail when run from a local harddrive. Try putting it on a server somewhere.