# JQuery .load() method isn't working in Google Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

Hi I am loading a page using jquery .load() method.
the page is loaded perfectly on the firefox but it isn't load when I am opening the page on the google chrome.

Do you guys have some solution.

```
<script>
          var xmlHttp;
          function initAjax() {
              try {
                  xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
              } catch(e) {
                  try {
                      xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); // Internet Explorer
                  } catch(e) {
                      try {
                          xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                      } catch(e) {
                          alert("No AJAX!?");
                          return false;
                      }
                  }
              }

              xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                  if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
                      document.getElementById('main_container').innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
                  }
              }
          }

function updateAjax(mypage) {
            var t=mypage;
            //alert(t);
                  if(t=="")
                  {
                      //alert("Welldone");   
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      xmlHttp.open("GET", t, true);
                      xmlHttp.send(null);
                  }
          }

window.onload = function() {
              initAjax();
          }
        </script>

        <div id="main_container" style="position: relative;">

        </div>

        <script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/docs.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/jRating.jquery.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
          $("#main_container").load("home.html");
        </script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990518/jquery-load-not-working-in-chrome

Comment: Why are you using XMLHttpRequest and ActiveXObject if you have jQuery available?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer..
Try to use this..

```
 <script>
      var xmlHttp;
      function initAjax() {
          try {
              xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
          } catch(e) {
              try {
                  xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); // Internet Explorer
              } catch(e) {
                  try {
                      xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                  } catch(e) {
                      alert("No AJAX!?");
                      return false;
                  }
              }
          }

          xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
                  document.getElementById('main_container').innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
              }
          }
      }

function updateAjax(mypage) {
        var t=mypage;
        //alert(t);
              if(t=="")
              {
                  //alert("Welldone");   
              }
              else
              {
                  xmlHttp.open("GET", t, true);
                  xmlHttp.send(null);
              }
      }

window.onload = function() {
          initAjax();
      }
    </script>

    <div id="main_container" style="position: relative;">

    </div>

    <script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/docs.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jRating.jquery.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#main_container").load("home.html"); }); 
    </script>
```

Comment: I had a similar problem. Try to host in the server and load. it will work fine. If you try to load the page from local chrome will not display it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is just that `.load()` for local files is blocked by Chrome for security reasons. If you are using it on a server it works, given that all of the files originate from the same place.

To enable a working version locally, try:

In Mac OS X, quite Chrome, enter in Terminal:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --allow-file-access-from-files
```

In Windows, quite Chrome, enter in Command Prompt:

```
chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files
```

(Maybe you actually have to have the path... I don't think so. If so, you'll have to find it yourself.)

In Linux, quite Chrome, enter something like this into the terminal:

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome --allow-file-access-from-files
```